# Archives widget doesn't work?

Tags: archives

I've seen the same thing in every theme I've tried: Main page shows ten (or more) most recent posts.  Click on a month in the archives list, more than a year back, and Wordpress generates the exact same list of posts.

Comment: Then you have a plugin which uses `query_posts` or another bad query or filter that is breaking page functionality.

Comment: That is, if you haven't modified all the themes you have tried

Comment: Would that be "Yost SEO"?  I don't like it anyway.  I'll remove it and see what happens. Just also discovered that comments are disabled though the edit screen says otherwise.  (On two themes)

Comment: Deactivated and deleted "Yost SEO" and "Embed Youtube" and the archives are fixed.  Change your comment to Answer and I'll check it.  Comments still broke—separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably have a plugin that either uses `query_posts`, are have a bad filter and/or query that is altering the the main query object (*`$wp_query`*) as you have this issue across all themes that you have tested.

You should deactivate your plugins one by one and check which one/s are causing the issue. Also, turn debug on and look for obvious errors

Comment: Yes, it was probably "Yost SEO" although I also deleted a Youtube embedder at the same time.  Thanks!